# Sending a SMS to the current device within Android JUnit test

Tags: android

I'm using the following code in a JUnit test to send a SMS to the current device:

```
// Get device phonenumber
TelephonyManager telMgr = (TelephonyManager) getActivity().getSystemService (Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String phoneNumber = telMgr.getLine1Number();
// Send SMS
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(phoneNumber, null, "sms body", null, null);
```

Tested in the emulator but this doesn't work, I have set the PHONE_STATE and set SEND_SMS permissions.
Does anybody know a better way to write a test that sends an SMS to the current device? (not using ADB)